# Joining the results of two queries with different field names

Tags: sql

I have two queries at present as below.

I have two fields CUSTOM6 and CUSTOM8.

They both store different plan ID's that a customer could be assigned to (a customer always has a planID in both custom6 and custom8)

I want to do a count essentially, for the total number of distinct customers on each plan ID. So, I really want to be able to join the two below query results into a single output.

I've had a look through other stack overflow topics & have seen Union is suggested.However, this didn't work for me.

Can you advise me?

Thanks

**Query 1**

```
SELECT custom8 as plan, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,

CASE 
WHEN instr(custom8, 'ROW') = True then 'ROW'
end as Region

from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom8, custom1
```

AND **Query 2**

```
SELECT custom6 as plan, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,
CASE 
WHEN instr(custom6, 'DOM') = True then 'DOM'
end as Region
from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom6, custom1;
```

The output from both queries is below. I essentially need query 2 (with field custom6) to sit directly under query 1 (with field custom8) as a single table.
[image]

Comment: What is the structure of your tables. Especially data types of custom8 and custom6? Could you add it to your query. You know CREATE TABLE ...

Comment: You should also be grouping by those case statements for proper aggregation

Comment: What exactly with UNION didn't work for you? What is your expected output?

Comment: Could you please explain why `UNION` did not work for you ? Did you also try with `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: Can you add the output that you are looking to get to these examples?

Comment: Can you confirm what rdbms you are using? Based on `instr(...) = True` expression I'm guessing mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Union` will get you separate rows for the same `billingplatform`, however, this is clearly not your intention. This is how you can achieve it theoretically:

```
select c1, c2
from (query1) t1
join (query2) t2
on t1.something = t2.something
```

Let's apply this in practice:

```
select t1.billingplatform, t1.plan as t1plan, t2.plan as t2plan, t1.msisdn + t2.msisdn as msisdn
from
(SELECT custom8 as plan, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,

CASE 
WHEN instr(custom8, 'ROW') = True then 'ROW'
end as Region

from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom8, custom1) t1
(SELECT custom6 as plan, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,
CASE 
WHEN instr(custom6, 'DOM') = True then 'DOM'
end as Region
from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom6, custom1) t2
on t1.billingplatform = t2.billingplatform
```

Note that this query will ignore records where either `t1` or `t2` does not have a pair for the other counterpart, therefore you might want to use outer join, defaulting `msisdn` to 0 in the main `select` clause.

It is quite possible that I misunderstood the problem. In that case I would like to kindly ask for further clarification.

EDIT

Since further information was given by the asker, I realized that instead of using a join we need union in this case after all.

```
(SELECT custom8 as plan, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,

CASE 
WHEN instr(custom8, 'ROW') = True then 'ROW'
end as Region

from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom8, custom1)
union all
(SELECT custom6 as plan, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,
CASE 
WHEN instr(custom6, 'DOM') = True then 'DOM'
end as Region
from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom6, custom1)
order by billingplatform
```

I have no time now to actually test this with MySQL, so if there are any problems, please, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I think it's almost what I need, but it still produces 2 plan fields. I've updated my description a bit, I hope that helps.

Comment: @Kieran you are welcome. So you need to have for example two records of C, the first having an msisdn of 119 and the other having a value of 111? If that is the case, we need to know whether there is any possibility to have the same value for custom6 as for custom8 for the same billingplatform?

Comment: Yep that is correct. The billing platform is likely to be duplicated however, custom6 and custom8 values should never match.Just to confirm, the msisdn is the count of users that meet that criteria

Comment: Sorry above was terribly worded - The billing platform will not be a unique value and custom6 and custom8 are very likely to have the same billing platform. However, custom6 values should never be the same as custom8 values. Just to confirm, the msisdn is the count of users that meet that criteria

Comment: @Kieran yes, billingplatform can be duplicated, as can be seen from the example given in your edited question. I was only wondering whether custom6 and custom8 can be duplicated, in which case aggregation would be needed. Since you told me it can be excluded, I have not included aggregation into my edit.

Comment: Thank you! Just getting one error related to the bracket at the beginning: " Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'custom8'" - any ideas??

Comment: @Kieran sorry about that, it must be a syntax error, I could not test this unfortunately, but I am sure the idea is good.

Comment: @Kieran if you run only the query inside the first parantheses, is it successfully executing the first query?

Comment: Ah, it needed to be union all, then it worked :) - thanks again!

Comment: @Kieran, I am happy to help. Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries will produce one line per 'plan' and billingplatform. I'm guessing your issue is that each 'plan' has a different domain, so you can only join on billingplatform. Joining only on billing platform won't give you what you want as you will get a cross-product on the plans.
In this case, what you need to do is convert the plans to the same domain.
Assuming the plan codes are composed of a region prefix and plan size, and you want to join on the plan size, you could try modifying your queries like this:

```
SELECT substr(custom6,4) as plan_size, custom1 as billingplatform, count(distinct MSISDN)as msisdn,
CASE 
WHEN custom1 = 'DISE' then 'Business'
WHEN custom1 = 'CUK' then 'Consumer'
end as BusinessConsumer,
CASE 
WHEN instr(custom6, 'DOM') = True then 'DOM'
end as Region
from kkudrfeed2
Group by custom6, custom1;
```